# When Select isSearchable i would like the keyboard to be in number mode

Tags: react-select

When Select isSearchable and device is mobile I would like the keyboard to be in number mode. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the `Input` component using the [components framework](https://react-select.com/components) and set the `pattern` prop to only allow digits if the current device is mobile.

The `pattern` prop (or rather attribute) on input elements checks the value of the input for input validation. With the right pattern, it controls the type of keyboard you get on mobile devices. `\d*` is a regex pattern that will only allow digits into the input.

```
const Input = (props) => <components.Input {...props} pattern={somehowCheckForMobile() ? "\\d*" : undefined} />;

<Select 
    { ... }
    components={{
        Input
    }}
/>
```

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/zn2ov3x5ml)

Comment: For some reason the Sandbox doesn't compile, but the solution does work.

Comment: Seems like an issue with CodeSandbox, because it happens to all my React sandboxes. Editing a file will fix the preview temporarily.